# Why was Deadpool's origin as being imbued with Wolverine's mutant healing factor changed?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, comic-adaptation

The Marvel comics character Deadpool, in 616 and most other incarnations, is a normal human given an offer that he couldn't resist when he developed cancer. The offer involved being experimented on and given a distilled copy of the X-Men character Wolverine's mutant healing factor. This is constantly referred to, and links Deadpool to Wolverine in a very intimate way. Mutants typically develop their powers during adolescence/puberty due to stress and hormones, the powers sometimes in response to environmental conditions or genetic history.

X-Men Origins: Wolverine has a DINO version of Deadpool (in Name Only), that not only inherits Wolverine's mutant healing factor, but a few others as well. Then X-Men Days of Future Past happens and wipes out this timeline.

The 2016 film, set in the new timeline, changes this by making Deadpool a latent mutant, who's powers only develop through repeated stress trials, and in response to environmental conditions (cancer, death). **His specific connection to Wolverine was removed, as was the overall connection to the shared backstory of the Weapon X program.**

As Wolverine and Deadpool exist in the same movie universe, with no complications like the other comic movie universe, ***why was this drastic change to the character's origin done?***

Comment: Even in game [deadpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(video_game)) he did mentioned his healing factor is credited somewhat to wolverine.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar that's because the game is based off the comics. Unfortunately its mostly based on the Daniel Way era *eww*

Comment: http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Deadpool-Decided-Ignore-X-Men-Movie-Timeline-111287.html

Comment: cause they couldn't afford hugh jackman in Deadpool ;-)

Comment: @DForck42 jokes aside, they wouldn't need to have Hugh in the film to mention "the serum was developed using the blood of a previous mutant test subject" wink wink nudge nudge.

Comment: @cde lol.  in all honesty, it was probably a deliberate attempt to be just a LITTLE bit further away from X-Men Origins: Wolverine.  that's just speculation though

Answer (score 3):

Interviews from the cast have stated that they wanted to distance themselves from the previous, negatively received X-Men movies (looking at you X-Men Origins: Wolverine).

> Obviously the goal is that fans appreciate the better versions of the character more than they dislike the continuity alteration…
>
> If you’re concerned that Deadpool will always drift a bit away from the larger X-Men world, however, I wouldn’t fret too much. Rhett Reese and Paul Wernick recognize the potential in the future for the main X-Men movies to catch up with their deadly anti-hero, and are mentally preparing to take on the narrative challenges that will be presented. Reese told me,
> We had fun with it, and at some point, I think we might have to make some hard decisions, but hopefully the X universe will have caught up by that point and it’ll make it easier on us.

It's likely a combination of this and management at Fox looking to play it safe by not directly linking a new venture with an established series of movies.

Source: [cinemablend.com](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Deadpool-Decided-Ignore-X-Men-Movie-Timeline-111287.html)